# Creating a plist file

Tags: iphone, xml, plist

I am new to iOS devlopement and i need your help.I need to create a plist file of a xml.The xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" ?>
<nutrition>

<nutritiontype item="Calories">
<milk>113</milk>
<fat>98</fat>
<fatfree>68</fatfree>
<pacific>60</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Total calories">
<milk>6g</milk>
<fat>4g</fat>
<fatfree>0g</fatfree>
<pacific>2g</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Saturated Fat">
<milk>4g</milk>
<fat>2g</fat>
<fatfree>0g</fatfree>
<pacific>0g</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Cholesterol">
<milk>26mg</milk>
<fat>15mg</fat>
<fatfree>0mg</fatfree>
<pacific>0mg</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Sodium">
<milk>94mg</milk>
<fat>105mg</fat>
<fatfree>105mg</fatfree>
<pacific>173mg</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Carbohydrates">
<milk>8g</milk>
<fat>10g</fat>
<fatfree>10g</fatfree>
<pacific>5g</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Dietary Fiber">
<milk>0g</milk>
<fat>0g</fat>
<fatfree>0g</fatfree>
<pacific>0g</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Sugars">
<milk>8g</milk>
<fat>10g</fat>
<fatfree>10g</fatfree>
<pacific>5g</pacific>
</nutritiontype>


<nutritiontype item="Protein">
<milk>6g</milk>
<fat>8g</fat>
<fatfree>8g</fatfree>
<pacific>4g</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

<nutritiontype item="Vitamin A">
<milk>5%</milk>
<fat>8%</fat>
<fatfree>8%</fatfree>
<pacific>0%</pacific>
</nutritiontype>


<nutritiontype item="Vitamin C">
<milk>2%</milk>
<fat>2%</fat>
<fatfree>2%</fatfree>
<pacific>0%</pacific>
</nutritiontype>

</nutrition>
```

Please give me some reference so that i can proceed.

Thanks..

Comment: Is this returned from a webservice/in a static file? Or are you doing this to include as a static plist in your Resources?

Comment: Thanks for quick response..

This is a static xml...

Answer (score 1):

If it's static, I'd just [recreate it by hand in Xcode.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#Property_List_Editor)

Comment: I agree, if your list is not too long then it would be faster to create it by hand.